# Getting the inside size of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a JFrame defined

```
JFrame frame;
frame = new JFrame();
```

I want to get the size of the inside of it.

I tried doing `frame.getContentPane().getSize()` but it the same value as `frame.getSize()` - the value with borders.

I also tried to do something with `frame.getInsets()` but it always returns `[0, 0, 0, 0]`

Do you have any other ideas on how I can get the inside size of a `JFrame`?

Comment: Create a JPanel and add it to the JFrame.  Get the size of the JPanel after rendering the JFrame.

Comment: *"Getting the inside size of JFrame"*  See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)  In this case, a better strategy would *probably* be to ensure the content suggests a size and then `pack()` the frame.  For anything better than 'probably', describe what you are going to **do** with the 'inside size of a frame'..

Comment: I am going to make all the components in the frame resize as the frame resizes the frame and i need the 'inside size of a frame' to calculator how big should these components be.

Comment: `I am going to make all the components in the frame resize as the frame resizes` - that is the job of the layout manager. Use a proper layout manager and the components will be resized automatically. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.

Answer (score 1):

You need to render the JFrame before you can get the size of it.
This can be done by

```
JFrame frame;
frame = new JFrame();
frame.setVisible(true);

System.out.println(frame.getContentPane().getSize());
```

If you try to get the size before its rendered it will print the current size, which is 0.

Comment: You're right. But this is not what I'm looking for. I want to find out how to get the size of the inside of the JFrame (without borders).